# Not able to create array for n number of values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

Hi i have the following array that comes from a html form

```
$job_title = 'Developer';
$job_skill = 'html,css,javascript';


$post_fields = array(
    'job_title' => $job_title,
    'skills' => $job_skill
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($post_fields);
echo "</pre>";
```

that gives the output as

```
Array
(
    [job_title] => Developer
    [skills] => html,css,javascript
)
```

I wanted to convert the skills to an array itself so i converted the $post_fields to

```
$post_fields = array(
    'job_title' => $job_title,
    'skills' => 
        array (
            0 => 'html',
            1 => 'css',
            2 => 'javascript'
        )
);
```

Now in the main code, "$job_skill" is a dynamic value and can have any number of skills. It's value can be null, can have 1 skill, 2 skill or any number of skill. The problem is that i am not able to create array of job_skill for 'n' number of values

Can anyone please help me with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php `explode` function which will convert string to array:

```
<?php
$job_title = 'Developer';
$job_skill = 'html,css,javascript';


$post_fields = array(
    'job_title' => $job_title,
    'skills' => explode(",",$job_skill)
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($post_fields);
echo "</pre>";
```

o/p:

```
Array
(
    [job_title] => Developer
    [skills] => Array
        (
            [0] => html
            [1] => css
            [2] => javascript
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert a string `"a,b,c"` to an array `("a", "b", "c")` you can use the PHP function `explode`:

```
$skills = explode(",", $job_skill);
```

Comment: Why is this answer upvoted more than B. Desai's more complete one?